# Creating prepared statements with Snowflake driver in Go

Tags: go, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create prepared statements using the Snowflake driver for Go: https://github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake

However, every time I try to prepare a statement that requires strings, it fails to bind them to the overall query.

Here is an example:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake"
)

func getData(db *sql.DB) error {

    tbl := "DATASET"
    s := "Bob"

    stmt := "INSERT INTO ? SELECT * FROM OTHER_TBL WHERE name = ?"

    _, err := db.Exec(stmt, dataset, s)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

The query always fails with a Syntax error stating it didn't recognize the `?`. I've also tried the `.Prepare()` method and I get the same result.

I've also tried single quoting the `?` placeholder, but in my actual query, I have several `?` and it doesn't bind any of them.

I'm left with only having success if I use `fmt.Sprintf()` but I'd like to avoid that method.

Comment: What version of the GO driver are you using and what OS? I've run the code you show here on an Ubuntu machine with Snowflake Go 1.6.17 and works fine for me.

Comment: @Sergiu Go 1.19, Snowflake Driver v 1.6.17, Windows 10 OS.

Comment: I've also used Go 1.19.5 on Linux and same driver version. Let me try on a Windows 10 VM.

Comment: Still works for me on a Windows 10 VM, unfortunately I cannot add a screenshot with query history in comments. I used the CITIBIKE_TRIPS free data set and created ahead an empty table like the CITIBIKE_TRIPS one and used this INSERT statement: **INSERT INTO CITIBIKE_TRIPS_S SELECT * FROM CITIBIKE_TRIPS where ride_id = ?**, where ride_id was hardcoded like in your example: **s := "E6F72AFF1DA83C4B"**. Insert was successful and I can see the row in the target table. Would you be able to post a query id of the failed statement?

Comment: @Sergiu. The error response from the driver is:

```001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 3 at position 3 unexpected '?'.
syntax error line 27 at position 3 unexpected '?'.```

This is in the actual query with real data I am working with, not the mockup I posted above but the DML is the same, I am inserting into based off a select. It runs fine using ```fmt.Sprintf()``` and ```%s``` interpolated fields, so I know that there isn't a typo.  All fields being passed into ```db.Exec()``` are go ```string```s

Comment: @Sergiu Also, I slightly amended my question. I am using a ```?``` to identify the table as well. In my original question I had a hardcoded ```tbl```. In actuality, the ```tbl``` is a ```string``` being prepared into the statement as well. Could this be the root cause? I am using ```?``` placeholders in the INSERT INTO as well as the WHERE.

Answer (score 1):

In your snippet code, you are parameterized the table name.

Snowflake implements [database/sql](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql) interfaces. as my experience with this library, parameterization table or column names are not allowed.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I could modify my approach to only parameterizing part of the query statement. Seems awkward though, might have to do some sort of string concatenation (first half of the query + parameterized part). I want the table name to be dynamic since CLI can provide an arg to a table name rather than hard-coding the table name in the statement.

Comment: You can use `fmt.Sprintf()` interpolation for table or column names. but don't forget to add validation to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: Right. What would validation particularly look like for SQL injection? This is part of the reason I wanted to go through the driver, but am interested in understanding what a solid validation would be to prevent SQL injection.